# Как сформировать MySQL запрос для вывода среднесуточных значений за текущий месяц?

Tags: mysql

Есть табличка с данными датчиков которые добавляются в таблицу каждые 30 минут. Какой запрос должен быть для вывода средних данных по каждому дню месяца?

Comment: select date(дата-время-события), avg(показание) from таблица group by date(дата-время-события)

Comment: @Mike, а можно ли сразу вывести все данные за месяц? В теории можно это реализовать средствами PHP. Но, как мне кажется, в MySQL подобная возможность есть

Comment: Этот запрос выдаст даже не за месяц а за вообще все время наблюдений. Если надо ограничиться конкретным месяцем - следует указать соответствующий where. А если вы понимали под этим 'выдать среднее за месяц', то опять же ограничиваем выборку where и убираем group by, получаем итоговое число за выбранный период. А если за весь период по месяцам, то модифицируем функцию в group by так, что бы из даты только месяц оставляла (например через date_format). SQL позволяет вообще выбрать все что угодно в любом разрезе

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp), AVG(value)
  FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```